# Catching exceptions in anonymous callback

Tags: c#, callback, try-catch

I'm not sure why this doesn't work. I have a suspicion it's something to do with separate working threads. I haven't been able to find any work on capturing exceptions in this manner.

I think I can create a Task object then run that but I would prefer to keep this architecture because the code contained within it is very complex.

```
public void MethodOne(){         
   try{
     MethodTwo(response =>{ 
        //Do something with the response
     });
   }
   catch(Exception error){ 
     //This never executes when method two throws exception
   }
}


public void MethodTwo(Action<Object> callback){
   //Conduct async call to external server 
   AppServer.MakeCall( response =>{       
      if(response.IsValid)
       callback(response.Object);
      else
        throw new FooException();
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this program is asynchronous, the callback isn't even being called until long after `MethodTwo` has returned and that thread has gone on to leave the `try` block and do bigger and better things.  The callback is being called by another thread at some point in the possibly distant future.

As you yourself mentioned, one possiblity is to use `Task` rather than using callbacks.  One of the major advantages of the TPL is how it approaches error handling.  If the asynchronous method returns a `Task`, you can not only add a callback using `ContinueWith` (or `await`), but you can handle errors in those continuations as well.

The way to handle this using callbacks is to accept two callbacks, one to call when the response is valid, and a second to call when there's an exception/error.  It's not nearly as pretty for the caller as using a `try/catch`, but it's the best you can do in a callback-based model.

Comment: For prosperity I opted for passing two callbacks. One for success and one for failure. I made them both anonymous so it worked out pretty tidy.

Answer (score 0):

Servy is right. Because it is already asynchronous using another thread or task is maybe not neccessary. But you can use a [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx)  for this.

```
    public void MethodOne()
    {
        MethodTwo()
            .ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                    // Handle error in task.Exception
                    ;
                else
                {
                    object obj = task.Result;
                    // Handle object
                }
            });
    }


    public Task<object> MethodTwo()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

        //Conduct async call to external server 
        AppServer.MakeCall(response =>
        {
            if (Response.IsValid)
                tcs.TrySetResult(response.Object);
            else
                tcs.TrySetException(new FooException());
        });

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

You could also do the try/catch inside the MethodTwo lambda argument and/or use the complete Response object instead of the response data Object instance only.`

```
    public void MethodOne()
    {
        MethodTwo(response =>
            {
                if (Response.IsValid)
                    callback(Response.Object);
                else
                    throw new FooException();  // Or error handling directly
            });
    }


    public void MethodTwo(Action<Response> callback)
    {
        //Conduct async call to external server 
        AppServer.MakeCall(response =>
        {
            callback(response);
        });
    }
```

If you are not allowed to have a reference to a Response object from MethodOne, and/or not allowed to change the callback signature, then you could call the callback action using the FooException as argument `callback(new FooException);`

```
    public void MethodOne()
    {
        MethodTwo(response =>
            {
                if (response is FooException)
                {
                    FooException exc = response as FooException;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle response;
                }
            });
    }

    public void MethodTwo(Action<object> callback)
    {
        //Conduct async call to external server 
        AppServer.MakeCall(response =>
        {
            if (Response.IsValid)
                callback(Response.Object);
            else
                callback(new FooException());
        });
    }
```